# RBAC configuration in elastic search with kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying out elastic search for the first time and I want to create a role which can access only a specific index (already created). How can I proceed with it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Elasticsearch is used, you can decide to install either the `shield`(less than 5.x) plugin or `x-pack`(paid subscription with a free trial period).

With x-pack installed, if you want to manage Roles in Kibana,

1. Login to Kibana
2. Navigate to Management -> Roles.
3. click on +Create role
4. Provide a name to your role
5. In the index privileges section, provide the index name and privileges required (read, write etc.)
6. save

With shield, you can manage roles using [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/defining-roles.html) document.

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt reply. Actually I already tried out the steps you’ve mentioned above.

Comment: The scenario is: let’s say I have created an index ‘Shakespeare’. I tried creating a user with index association with Shakespeare but I don’t get anything after logging in as that user.

Comment: If you're using Kibana to view the documents as user-x, you need to add user-x to kibana_user role along with the role that provides read access.

Comment: Tried out this option as well. But it didn’t meet our requirements exactly. But still, thanks a lot for so prompt replies