# Elasticsearch 5.6 authentication

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am usig elasticsearch 5.6 version.

Is there a way to add password to elassticsearch without an x-pack plugin and gold license?

I saw that x-pack supports security with basic license, but only from 6.8 version.

Currently, I can't upgrade elasticsearch and look for another way to add authentication (RBAC) to elasticsearch 5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Unfortunately, before 6.8 as you already mentioned basic X-pack security is not available and if you need RBAC at field and document level then it's not even available in Gold license and for that, you need to buy platinum or enterprise license.

I would suggest you go through the Elastic stack security section under [Elastic subscription](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) to see what is included and what is not included.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answer, you can look at [this shield] (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/index.html)

You can refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884555/rbac-configuration-in-elastic-search-with-kibana)

This is the way with 5.6 ES and kibana.

Comment: from 5.6 shield is part of x-pack